# How to get data via relationships with APIv4?

Tags: api

*Wilma* has  relationship: *is campaigner at* organisation *System Change Not Charity*.

How can I get a list of individuals like Wilma and the organisations that they are campaigners for?

I've read the [documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/v4/joins/) but I can't figure out how I would join on relationship?

I tried this which I thought would at least give me the names of people with that campaigner relationship type, but it gives nothing.

- Entity: Contact
- Action: get

```
{                                                                                                                                                                                           
    "select": ["display_name"],                                                                                                                                                               
    "where": [                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
      ["relationships.relationship_type_id", "=", 15]                                                                                                                                          
    ],                                                                                                                                                                                        
    "limit": 25,                                                                                                                                                                              
    "checkPermissions": false                                                                                                                                                                 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you're after but works for me; the 'join on' is a bit hidden in the 'Select' box.

```
CRM.api4('Relationship', 'get', {
  select: ["contact_a.display_name"],
  where: [["relationship_type_id", "=", 5]],
  limit: 25
}).then(function(relationships) {
  // do something with relationships array
}, function(failure) {
  // handle failure
})
```

Answer (score 1):

For the part about making your first-step example work, use 'contact_a.display_name' instead of display_name.

Also it's missing from your example but it would be `'Relationship', 'get',` at the very beginning, so the whole thing, to also get the org, is

```
$relationships = civicrm_api4('Relationship', 'get', [
  'select' => [
    'contact_a.display_name', 'contact_b.display_name'
  ],
  'where' => [
    ['relationship_type_id', '=', 15],
  ],
  'checkPermissions' => false,
]);
```

Comment: So are you saying I MUST do relationships from the relationships entity? Can't I start from contact, add relationship, add the related contact?

Comment: I find the api is always the reverse for joins. You kind of work backwards. See also https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/28126/fetch-membership-type-along-with-the-contact-details-with-civicrm-api/28131#28131. You could start from contact and write a procedural loop, but then it's not really a join.

Comment: Ok, so it it basically the case that APIv4 can do joins but only joins that are 1 deep? i.e. I can go Relationship to two contacts (and a relationship type); but I can't go contact → relationship → contact, because that's 2 deep. Or, for example, I couldn't get the phone number of the contact in your example (because that's relationship → contact → phone)?

Comment: I don't know the answer. Maybe there's a syntax for it. Or maybe with chaining, but then I get the impression from the docs that chaining isn't saving db calls vs doing a loop, just two or three less lines of code than writing your own loop.